# JSLint error - XML Serializer

Tags: javascript, xmlserializer, jslint

The code works fine but when i validate using JSLint it gives me the following error

```
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
```

JSLint error : XMLSerializer was used before it was defined.

```
var serializer = window.XMLSerializer();
```

The above code works fine in IE and Firefox and doesnt throw a JSLint error. But it doesnt work in Chrome.
The function is as follows :

```
this.XMLtoString = function (elem) {

        var serialized;
        try { 
            var serializer = window.XMLSerializer();
            serialized = serializer.serializeToString(elem);
        }
        catch (e) {
            //Internet Explorer has a different approach to serializing XML
            serialized = elem.xml;
        }

        return serialized;
    };
```

I also tried adding the following line above the function.It did not help
/* global XMLSerializer */

Please help in writing a function that uses XMLSerializer without a JSLint error and which works across all browsers.

Comment: Probably `XMLSerializer()` is a global function. Just add it to "Globals list".

Comment: @Teemu : It is not a function created by me.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me in Chrome if you use:

```
var serializer = window.XMLSerializer();
```

Alternatively, you can use your original `new XMLSerializer();` code and then place this directive at the top of your file:

```
/*global XMLSerializer */
```

There must be *no space* between `/*` and `global` (people aren't kidding when they say JSLint is picky!).